# No puedo agregar botones con íconos

Tags: java, android, app, navegador-web, apk

Estoy intentando hacer un navegador con botones simples, los cuales tendrán imágenes .png como íconos. Mi aplicación no funciona cuando uso:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/button_icon"
android:contentDescription="@string/button_icon_desc"
... />
```

Pero funciona perfectamente cuando se ocupa:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_text"
... />
```

Aquí el URL de error generador por URL:

> time: 1615083200067 msg: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
> stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.androidbrowser/com.androidbrowser.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be
> cast to android.widget.Button     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3431)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7661)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:594)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
> cannot be cast to android.widget.Button   at
> com.androidbrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)    at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)    at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3404)
> ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que indica el LogCat esta definido aquì:

```
msg: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

indica que estas tratando de realizar la conversiòn de una vista a otro tipo diferente.

Asegura que al obtener la referencia del botòn por su id, el tipo sea el mismo que defines en el layout, por ejemplo si defines un `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    ...
    ...
 />
```

obten su referencia indicando el tipo `ImageButton`:

```
ImageButton boton = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.myButton);
```

---

Si defines un si defines un `Button`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    ...
    ...
 />
```

obten su referencia indicando el tipo `Button`

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.myButton);
```